# java applet code stop execution in middlie of code and getting cipersuit issue

Tags: java, security, ssl, jar, applet

hi my java applet program stops working may be because getting several issues in log as follows. it seems some ignore cipher suit but not sure exact issue. please help anyone to find issue from my log below what cause my applet stop working.i tried to handle issue getting in log like ingore cipher suit by install policies in jre home but stil same result in log and also disabled some ssl in firefox in client also not working.

```
Java Plug-in 11.144.2.01 x86
Using JRE version 1.8.0_144-b01 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\agcappssupport
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@fed6f3
security: Expected Main URL: http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/plugin.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sacrypt_uof-4.0.35.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-codec-1.4.jar
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar with cookie "2facookie=juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf"
network: ResponseCode for http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar : 200
network: Encoding for http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar : null
network: Server response: (length: 76327, lastModified: Wed Oct 11 16:07:04 SGT 2017, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/x-jar)
network: Downloading resource: http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar
    Content-Length: 76,327
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar to File C:\Users\AGCAPP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache36268808298588229.tmp
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1507530373227
security: blacklist: check contains zZkJRFeBfe8oLiLGDgdog4/AMfXGU4q55BkZv4OUQGw=, state now NEED_LOAD
security: blacklist: loadCache
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
security: Trusted libraries list file not found
security: blacklist: check contains zZkJRFeBfe8oLiLGDgdog4/AMfXGU4q55BkZv4OUQGw=, state now IN_MEMORY
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
network: Disconnect connection to http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar
network: Downloaded http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar: C:\Users\AGCAPP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache36268808298588229.tmp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@36109315: 1
security: Grant connect perm for http://lp-ua-ed/authApplet.jar : java.security.Permissions@1c39ff2 (
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80/-" "*:*")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80" "*:*")
)
    plugin2
    http://lp-ua-ed/templates/login2fa.w3p?url=/templates/reinit.w3p;fromUrl=http%253A%252F%252Flp-ua-ed%253A80%252Fworkflow%252Fall_assign.w3p%253Btid%25253D9cda84e2-0a07-4a0a-9b55-7fc0cd6db00c%253Btname%25253Dall_assignments: code=com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet debug=1 idpport=7090 archive=/authApplet.jar,/depend/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,/depend/plugin.jar,/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar,/depend/sacrypt_uof-4.0.35.jar,/depend/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar,/depend/commons-codec-1.4.jar idpprotocol=http codebase=http://lp-ua-ed/ name=myApplet width=0 style=position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px; idpserver=lp-ua-ed id=myApplet mayscript=true height=0  app_model=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
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 433073 us, pluginInit dt 4709413 us, TotalTime: 5142486 us
init
origin Protocol : http
LoadCACertificate|Cert Type:agcdc1.jks
LoadCACertificate| fromCert:java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream@15b8f72
leapHome ********** C:\Users\agcappssupport\leap\agcdc1.jks
false
 javax.net.ssl.trustStore null
 Trust store Path C:\Users\agcappssupport\leap\agcdc1.jks
 Trust store Password  changeit
init edsServer: lp-ua-ed
edsProtocol=http, edsServer=lp-ua-ed, edsPort=
idpProtocol=http, idpServer=lp-ua-ed, idpPort=7090 
security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
security: The OCSP support is disabled
security: The CRL support is disabled
security: Revocation check disabled
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.144
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.141
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.144
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.141
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 79CA1C7DAAF7BC83BB16E5387E16F200B7FD83A0E72D89B985B2E5A992EEEC68
security: Decision cert hash not matching
Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
security: User has granted the privileges to the code for this session only
security: Saving certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: Saved certificates in Deployment session certificate store
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 79CA1C7DAAF7BC83BB16E5387E16F200B7FD83A0E72D89B985B2E5A992EEEC68
security: Decision time stored for ai: Appinfo:
type = 2
title = null
vendor = null
from = http://lp-ua-ed/depend/sa2fa_uof-4.0.35.jar
security = 0
lapURL = http://lp-ua-ed//myApplet/lp-ua-ed
appArgs = ##docbase:http://lp-ua-ed/templates/login2fa.w3p##Parameters:YXJjaGl2ZQ===L2F1dGhBcHBsZXQuamFyLC9kZXBlbmQvY29tbW9ucy1odHRwY2xpZW50LTMuMS5qYXIsL2RlcGVu 
userPin=9300Tg3w
ctx=53163568
Creating object of connectsession with idpserver : lp-ua-ed domain : AGC token : juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf
security: Grant connect perm for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar : java.security.Permissions@12a469a (
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80/-" "*:*")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80" "*:*")
) ZC9wbHVnaW4uamFyLC9kZXBlbmQvc2EyZmFfdW9mLTQuMC4zNS5qYXIsL2RlcGVuZC9zYWNyeXB0
X3VvZi00LjAuMzUuamFyLC9kZXBlbmQvY29tbW9ucy1sb2dnaW5nLTEuMS4xLmphciwvZGVwZW5k
L2NvbW1vbnMtY29kZWMtMS40Lmphcg==,Y29kZQ===Y29tLnRlcmF0ZXh0LmxlYXAuYXBwbGV0LkF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uQXBwbGV0,Y29kZWJhc2U==aHR0cDovL2xwLXVhLWVkLw==,ZGVidWc==MQ==,aGVpZ2h0=MA==,aWQ==bXlBcHBsZXQ=,aWRwcG9ydA===NzA5MA==,aWRwcHJvdG9jb2w==aHR0cA==,aWRwc2VydmVy=bHAtdWEtZWQ=,amF2YV9hcmd1bWVudHM==,bWF5c2NyaXB0=dHJ1ZQ==,bmFtZQ===bXlBcHBsZXQ=,c3R5bGU==cG9zaXRpb246IGZpeGVkOyB0b3A6IDBweDsgbGVmdDogMHB4Ow==,d2lkdGg==MA==,
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
Enter user name and password
netscape.javascript.JSException: No such method "getUserName" on JavaScript object
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.newJSException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.waitForReply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.MessagePassingJSObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.perform2FA(AuthenticationApplet.java:320)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.access$000(AuthenticationApplet.java:21)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet$1.run(AuthenticationApplet.java:293)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet$1.run(AuthenticationApplet.java:290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.submit2FA(AuthenticationApplet.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
calling hello...
session: com.teratext.leap.applet.connect2FAsession@283387
Connecting to URL :http://lp-ua-ed:7090/2faHello.aspx
security: Grant connect perm for http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar : java.security.Permissions@1595382 (
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80/-" "*:*")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://lp-ua-ed:80" "*:*")
)

security: Missing Codebase manifest attribute for: http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
security: Missing Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase manifest attribute for: http://lp-ua-ed/depend/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: The certificate has expired, need to check timestamping info
security: No timestamping info available
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/commons-logging.properties with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/commons-logging.properties with cookie "2facookie=juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf"
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with cookie "2facookie=juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf"
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory with cookie "2facookie=juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://lp-ua-ed/META-INF/services/org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3.run(LogFactory.java:1359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getResourceAsStream(LogFactory.java:1355)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<clinit>(HttpMethodBase.java:104)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.connect2FAsession.run(connect2FAsession.java:150)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.perform2FA(AuthenticationApplet.java:334)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.access$000(AuthenticationApplet.java:21)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet$1.run(AuthenticationApplet.java:293)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet$1.run(AuthenticationApplet.java:290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.teratext.leap.applet.AuthenticationApplet.submit2FA(AuthenticationApplet.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/org/apache/log4j/Category.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://lp-ua-ed/org/apache/log4j/Category.class with cookie "2facookie=juzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf"
Calling try post with tokenjuzzI7byw2Syo865kILSVFmEuZ8Wof6aszb2JKp5TzdkIr5cgpol1vjQ2nLx94Bf
check post values: org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@6e8453
check client values: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient@193d91c
responseString:null
check post values2: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient@193d91c
NTLMUtils: false
network: Checking for update at: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar
security: JSS is not configured
Success 1

Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
network: Connecting https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Updating file at: C:\Users\agcappssupport\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\securitypack.jar from url: https://javadl-esd-secure.oracle.com/update/securitypack.jar
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline.checkForUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getLastModified(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: `applets` Oh I remember them from 20 years ago.  The error as is stated is `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Comment: yes..still lock with this issue..looking in different way to solve..

Comment: *"Oh I remember them from 20 years ago"* annnnd, I'm still trying to forget them